# SD-WAN edge and physical high-end router

Tags: wan, sdn, wan-optimizer, sd-wan

Are physical routers, who have different management interfaces (SNMP, NETCONF, and so on), able to speak to an SD-WAN controller?
In other words, can I have an SD-WAN by establishing a specific SD-WAN controller and orchestrator with a router that has just different management interfaces?
which capabilities does a router have to support, to be used as an SD-WAN edge?

I took a look at MEF 70 standard and didn't really find answers to my question.

Comment: A router needs to have code to do SD-WAN. For example, Cisco ISR routers can be loaded with a specific code version to do SD-WAN, or they can run a standard code version that does not.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "high-end." For really high-end routers, you do not want SD-WAN.

Comment: @RonMaupin  by high-end, I mean some white boxes like EdgeCore 5916 which is able to have some NOSs on it, and those NOSs don't say anything about SD-WAN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are physical routers, who have different management interfaces (SNMP, NETCONF, and so on), able to speak to an SD-WAN controller?

No, not generally. The router needs to provide access to its forwarding plane, e.g. using OpenFlow (which the controller needs to support as well). You cannot use configuration protocols like SNMP or NETCONF.

Comment: I did a short survey on Cisco-Viptella products and some other SD-WAN vendors and it seems to me that these SD-WAN routers are too proprietary. Even I think that SDN routers (supporting OpenFlow) are not "SD-WAN ready".